# How to make case sensitive URLs with Rails / Friendly-Id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-url, friendly-id

I am using the `Friendly-Id` `gem` to create pretty URL's. I would like to create case sensitive URLs and redirect all the other case versions of the same URL to the default one with a `301` status.

```
/profile/Jack-Wild # default URL
/profile/jack-wild # redirect to /profile/Jack-Wild
/profile/jaCk-Wild # redirect to /profile/Jack-Wild
```

`Friendly_Id` downcase's slugs and only matches and accepts downcase URLs, `404`ing everything else.

The feasable solution would be to maintain a `slug_case_sensitive` ( Jack-Wild ) as well as the default downcase version of `slug` ( jack-wild ).

Then make `Friendly_Id` search by the `slug` column with `params[:id].downcase` and if `params[:id] != slug_case_sensitive` redirect to the preferred URL ( `/profile/slug_case_sensitive` ).

This is my idea on how to achieve it, with a few puzzles missing, hoping someone could help filling them in.

Modify the create and update slug methods, to create and update both versions of the slug. This would be only 1 method: `set_slug`:

```
# Sets the slug.
def set_slug(normalized_slug = nil)
  if should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    candidates = FriendlyId::Candidates.new(self, normalized_slug || send(friendly_id_config.base))
    slug = slug_generator.generate(candidates) || resolve_friendly_id_conflict(candidates)
    send "#{friendly_id_config.slug_column}=", slug
  end
end
private :set_slug
```

Suppose slug is not downcased. Should changing:
`send "#{friendly_id_config.slug_column}=", slug`
with: 
`send "#{friendly_id_config.slug_column}=", slug.downcase`
`send "#{friendly_id_config.slug_column_case_sensitive}=", slug`
be enough ? Also, how to add and set `friendly_id_config.slug_column_case_sensitive` option ?

And then, change `user_path(@user)` and `<%= link_to "My profile", current_user %>` to return the case sensitive URL. But no idea of a better way than `user_path(id:@user.slug_case_sensitive)` which is ugly and also I would have to change it everywhere and not sure if it can be done in 3rd party gems...

Any ideas on this would help and be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe different approach could be applied in this situation: most likely you'll use your Rails app behind Nginx as a proxy. Then it's possible to rewrite all requests for profiles with upcased letters in them to canonical variant. It will be faster than making additional DB requests and using whole Rails stack. Also it could be much simpler to implement.

Comment: It's not just the first letters upcased, that I'm trying to obtain, maybe the examples used wheren't the best, it's not just /profile/Jon-Smith, but also /profile/JonFK. And this is actually where it makes sense to use case sensitive URLS, because /profile/JonFK has a meaning, while /profile/Jonfk, not so much

Answer (score 1):

You can override the method `normalize_friendly_id` in your model:

```
def normalize_friendly_id(value)
  value.to_s.parameterize(preserve_case: true)
end
```

It relies on [ActiveSupport parameterize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize) which accepts a `preserve_case` option.